# Ordenação das tags inclusas no título das perguntas

Tags: bug

A imagem do screenshot já diz tudo.

O título da página recebe uma das tags e aparentemente escolhe a primeira por ordem alfabética.

Aqui, o assunto é PHP mas como o AP adicionou a tag `mysql`, esta ganhou prioridade para compor o título da página.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma sugestão óbvia é manter a ordem das tags que o AP definiu. Ou existe um motivo para manter da forma atual?

Comment: Mas a pergunta não é sobre php **e** mysql?

Comment: Dado o contexto, o mysql tem baxíssima relevância. Quase nula na verdade... @EMBarbosa

Comment: Entendi. Faz sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) não aparece pois no título existe o termo PHP já, então o sistema desconsidera, se editar e remover a "palavra" php, automaticamente o sistema irá trocar o prefixo de:

```
mysql - xxxxx
```

por

```
php - xxxxxx
```

Isto é algo do próprio sistema da SO, evitar repetições de palavras nos titulos, creio que antigamente (bem no começo do SOen) nem existia as tags em titulos, mas o pessoal procurava orientar os novos usuários a adicionarem, no entanto poucos faziam, então o sistema passou a adicionar uma das tags sozinho (que tem maior prioridade), no entanto ele desconsidera tags que já estejam como palavras no titulo dando prioridade para a próxima tag.

Comment: Bem observado. Mas ainda assim cria uma confusão com tags no início. Dando impressão de que o assunto é mais relacionado as tags do início.  Pelo menos foi essa a experiência que tive e por isso abri essa discussão.

Comment: @DanielOmine mas concorda comigo que se a pessoa criar um título `foo bar baz com PHP?` e adicionar a tag `php` isto seria redundância? Quero dizer o que importa é o titulo ser intuitivo, o uso da tag ali no prefixo é mais para questões de indexadores orgânicos.

Comment: Sim claro, por isso a discussão, se é realmente útil a inclusão das tags.

Comment: Creio que sim, pela questão do problema de usuários que não colocam as tags, isso é um problema em todos sites da rede, creio que seja mesmo uma questão mais voltada aos indexadores, por isto a preocupação por parte da SO. Vou dar uma olhada no Metão para ver se tem alguma postagem oficial ou no blog deles, quando encontrar lhe mando o link ;)

Comment: Fiz um teste e deu exatamente como respondeu.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215540

Comment: Nesse teste, tentei colocar o PHP por último nas tags mas o sistema reordena conforme você colocou na resposta. O sistema ordena as tags segundo o ranking das mesmas. Como o PHP é maior que as outras, fica sempre em primeiro.
Acho isso um pouco confuso pois se eu perguntar sobre HTML, porém envolvendo um pouco de PHP, então nas tags o PHP terá prioridade para uma pergunta focada em HTML. (apenas exemplo)..
 Notei também que apenas uma tag é prefixada no título, desde que não exista a tag já presente no título.

Answer (score 5):

Em tempo, caso isso seja algo que possa ser alterado: eu acho que exibir o nome da tag no título é desnecessário. Se você abrir várias abas você provavelmente vai saber qual é a tag principal de cada uma, mas não do que se trata cada uma. É mais produtivo deixar a tag no final do título ou removê-la completamente.

Então, se for possível uma alteração, eu sugiro a remoção da tag no título.

Comment: Ou colocar no final?

Comment: @bigown pra mim é ruído mesmo no final.

Comment: Penso o mesmo, que são ruídos. Mas pode ter alguma justificativa. Talvez SEO. Por isso preferi não sugerir a total remoção e perguntei se há um motivo. Se não houver motivo, remover essas tags do título me parece a melhor opção.